# COUNT added twice with JOIN Issue

Tags: mysql, join, count

I am working on project where I have reports that have three states its **"checked","inprocess"                   and "completed"**

Got two tables!

tbl_tracking - for keeping track of reports

```
    report_id   usr_id   date        status
    ----------------------------------------------
    0000        abc      2014/04/05  checked
    0001        abc      2014/04/05  checked
    0000        abc      2014/04/05  inprocess
    0001        abc      2014/04/05  completed
    0002        abc      2014/04/06  completed
    0004        xyz      2014/04/05  checked
    0005        xyz      2014/04/06  checked
```

tbl_timestatus- for keeping track of time employees have worked on reports

```
    usr_id   date        time_worked (hrs)
    ----------------------------------------------
    abc      2014/04/05  6
    abc      2014/04/06  5
```

Now I want to create a view to always display up-to-date status of everything so I code this

```
    CREATE VIEW VW_STATUS AS
    SELECT tb1.usr_id, tb1.date,
    COUNT(CASE tb1.status WHEN 'checked' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS checkedcount,
    COUNT(CASE tb1.status WHEN 'inprocess' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS inprocesscount,
    COUNT(CASE tb1.status WHEN 'completed' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS compltedcount,
    CASE WHEN (tb1.usr_id=tb2.usr_id AND tb1.date=tb2.date) THEN tb2.time_worked ELSE NULL END AS timeworked
    FROM tbl_tracking tb1, tbl_timestatus tb2
    GROUP BY tb1.usr_id, tb1.date;
```

Expected Output:

```
    usr_id   date        checkedcount   inprocesscount   completedcount   timeworked
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    abc      2014/04/05  2              1                1                6
    abc      2014/04/06  0              0                1                5
    xyz      2014/04/05  1              0                0                NULL
    xyz      2014/04/06  1              0                0                NULL
```

Actual Output:

```
    usr_id   date        checkedcount   inprocesscount   completedcount   timeworked
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    abc      2014/04/05  4              2                2                6
    abc      2014/04/06  0              0                2                5
    xyz      2014/04/05  2              0                0                NULL
    xyz      2014/04/06  2              0                0                NULL
```

**While the "timeworked" values remain correct, the count(*)'s add themselves twice!!                   There is some problem with join! Need help on same..**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try like below. See a sample fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b24c/6

```
CREATE VIEW VW_STATUS AS
SELECT tb1.usr_id, tb1.date,
COUNT(CASE tb1.status WHEN 'checked' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS checkedcount,
COUNT(CASE tb1.status WHEN 'inprocess' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS inprocesscount,
COUNT(CASE tb1.status WHEN 'completed' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS compltedcount,
tb2.time_worked
FROM tbl_tracking tb1
LEFT JOIN tbl_timestatus tb2
   ON tb1.usr_id=tb2.usr_id 
    AND tb1.date=tb2.date   
    GROUP BY tb1.usr_id, tb1.date , tb2.time_worked
    ORDER BY tb1.usr_id;
```

Which results in

[image]

Answer (score 0):

join tbl1 and tb2 on tb1.usr_id=tb2.usr_id AND tb1.date=tb2.date. Note that the time worked is correct.